# how to show only HTML elements that match the element selected by the drop-down list

Tags: javascript, match, html-select, nodelist

How to show only HTML elements that match the element selected by the drop-down list ?

I want to show in my page only the element that matchup with the value that I choose in drop-down list

When I changed the value of select element to 3 i get the text Nodelist in the body of html

```js
const divs_exept_3 = document.querySelectorAll("body > div:not(.element3)")
const listOperations = document.querySelector('#elements');
listOperations.addEventListener('change', () => {
  if (listOperations.value === "3") {
    document.body.innerHTML = divs_exept_3;
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="element1">
  <p>
    this is element 1
  </p>
</div>
<div class="element2">
  <p>
    this is element 2
  </p>
</div>
<div class="element3">
  <p>
    this is element 3
  </p>
</div>
<div class="element1">
  <p>
    this is element 1
  </p>
</div>
<div class="element2">
  <p>
    this is element 2
  </p>
</div>
<div class="element3">
  <p>
    this is element 3
  </p>
</div>
<select id="elements">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You want search functionality based on select?

Comment: I made you a snippet and fixed your typos

Comment: when i select the number in the drop-down list i want to show me only the element that has the class  element 1 and 2 but not element3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working script doing what I expect you want

```js
const allDivs = document.querySelectorAll("body > div")
allDivs.forEach(div => div.hidden = true);
const listOperations = document.getElementById('elements');
listOperations.addEventListener('change', function() {
  const idx = this.value;
  allDivs.forEach(div => div.hidden = !div.classList.contains(`element${idx}`))
});
```

```html
<div class="element1">
  <p>
    this is element 1
  </p>
</div>
<div class="element2">
  <p>
    this is element 2
  </p>
</div>
<div class="element3">
  <p>
    this is element 3
  </p>
</div>
<div class="element1">
  <p>
    this is element 1
  </p>
</div>
<div class="element2">
  <p>
    this is element 2
  </p>
</div>
<div class="element3">
  <p>
    this is element 3
  </p>
</div>
<select id="elements">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can achieve the same using CSS also.**

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="element1">
        <p>this is element 1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="element2">
        <p>this is element 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="element3">
        <p>this is element 3</p>
      </div>
      <div class="element1">
        <p>this is element 1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="element2">
        <p>this is element 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="element3">
        <p>this is element 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <style>
      .hide {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
    <select id="elements">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <script>
      function hideAll() {
        // Get container children
        const elements = document.getElementById("container").children;
        // Loop through children and hide it
        for (let element of elements) {
          element.classList.add("hide");
        }
      }

      const listOperations = document.querySelector("#elements");
      listOperations.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
        //  Capture selected value
        const selectedValue = e.target.value;
        // Get all selected elements by class name
        const selectedElements = document.querySelectorAll(
          `.element${selectedValue}`
        );
        // Make sure to hide previously selected values
        hideAll();
        for (let elem of selectedElements) {
          // Unhide/ show dropdown selected values
          elem.classList.remove("hide");
        }
      });
      // First time hide all elements (if you want)
      // hideAll()
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```